# Call to a member function delete() on string

Tags: php, laravel

So I get an error when I want to delete the cart, the error is Call to a `member function delete() on string`. I use groupby because so I can add up the total_product that matches the user_id and store_id. How to solve it?

**Controller**

```
public function storebilling(Request $request, $id)
{

$cart = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('store_id', $id)->get();
$carts = $cart->groupBy(fn ($i) => $i->Product->Store->name);


$orders = Orders::where('user_id', Auth()->user()->id)->latest()->get();

if ($carts) {
    foreach ($carts as $cart => $items) {
        foreach($items as $item){
            foreach ($orders->take(1) as $order) {
                OrderDetails::create([
                    'product_id' => $item->product_id,
                    'order_id' => $order->id,
                    'price' => $item->product->price * ((100 - $item->product->discount) / 100),
                    'qty' => $item->qty,
                    'discount' => $item->product->discount
                ]);
            }
        }
        $cart->delete();
    }
} else {
    return redirect('/cart');
}
```

So, The error in line `$cart->delete();`
How to solve it?

Comment: $cart has no delete() method you can call.

Comment: Evidently, `$cart` is a string. Strings don't have a delete() function (or any other function, since they're a simple type). That's what the error is telling you. `var_dump($cart);` if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: `$cart` is the key of the carts collection or array, so would be a string or integer, but never an object. You'll need to use that value to load the cart object/model to delete.

Comment: Also, creating elements by the loop isn't a good idea because it will execute a lot of SQL queries. You can insert multiple records together. In laravel you can use [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements) method.

Comment: unrelated to your question: ```if ($carts)``` will always be true as ```groupBy()``` is returning a truthy object even if the collection is empty

Comment: why are you grouping them by store name? doesn't seem like you are using that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```php
foreach ($carts as $cart) {
    foreach($cart->items as $item){
```

And make sure that you have a relation in the `Cart` model named `items()`.

Comment: Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: If `$carts` is a collection including some models (`$cart`, in our code), and if your `$cart` is a model that has a relation named `items`, your code works. Consider that `$cart` is a model, not `$carts`. Don't use `items` on `$carts`.

Comment: no, there is no relation

Comment: ```$carts``` is a ```Collection<string, Collection>``` so ```$cart``` is a ```Collection<int, Cart>``` it would need another foreach loop which can eliminated by removing the ```groupBy```